# Issue starting Cassandra. A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, cassandra

I installed openjdk, and cassandra via brew. I got this error when I started cassandra with `cassandra -f`:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010df65ab8, pid=52667, tid=0x0000000000008603
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_275) (build 1.8.0_275-bre_2020_11_16_16_29-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.275-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x565ab8]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.52667
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/my_laptop/hs_err_pid52667.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

After I saw that I tried uninstalling cassandra, and uninstalling openjdk. I installed regular java from oracle. When I run `java --version`, I now see this:

```
java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I compiled and ran a basic HelloWorld.java file to make sure my command line `java`/`javac` were working correctly. I then reinstalled cassandra via homebrew. But atlas I see the same error. If I start it with `brew services start cassandra` I get an error:

```
➜  ~ brew services list             
Name       Status  User          Plist
cassandra  error
```

And with `cassandra -f`, the exact same error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,063 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:92 - Configuration location: file:/usr/local/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,283 Config.java:536 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@2aa5fe93; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@5c1a8622; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,284 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,284 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 998MB
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,284 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 998MB
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,470 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,470 DatabaseDescriptor.java:773 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,669 JMXServerUtils.java:253 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,676 CassandraDaemon.java:490 - Hostname: Peters-Mac.hsd1.ca.comcast.net
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,676 CassandraDaemon.java:497 - JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_275
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,677 CassandraDaemon.java:498 - Heap size: 3.900GiB/3.900GiB
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,678 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 7167616(6999K) committed = 7208960(7040K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,678 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 19574984(19116K) committed = 20054016(19584K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,678 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2344344(2289K) committed = 2490368(2432K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,679 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 859045888(838912K) used = 240576832(234938K) committed = 859045888(838912K) max = 859045888(838912K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,679 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 107347968(104832K) used = 0(0K) committed = 107347968(104832K) max = 107347968(104832K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,679 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 3221225472(3145728K) used = 0(0K) committed = 3221225472(3145728K) max = 3221225472(3145728K)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,679 CassandraDaemon.java:505 - Classpath: /usr/local/etc/cassandra:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/build/classes/main:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/build/classes/thrift:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/apache-cassandra-3.11.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/hppc-0.5.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jackson-core-2.9.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jackson-databind-2.9.10.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/javax.inject.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jflex-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jna-4.2.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/joda-time-2.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/ohc-core-0.4.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/lib/jsr223/*/*.jar::/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,681 CassandraDaemon.java:507 - JVM Arguments: [-Xloggc:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/logs/gc.log, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms4096M, -Xmx4096M, -Xmn1024M, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/usr/local/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password, -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/libexec/sigar-bin, -Dcassandra.libjemalloc=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/usr/local/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=/usr/local/var/lib/cassandra, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes]
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,786 StartupChecks.java:140 - jemalloc seems to be preloaded from /usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib
WARN  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,787 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,789 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,809 SigarLibrary.java:57 - Could not initialize SIGAR library org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getFileSystemListNative()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem; 
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,809 SigarLibrary.java:185 - Sigar could not be initialized, test for checking degraded mode omitted.
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:28,941 QueryProcessor.java:116 - Initialized prepared statement caches with 15 MB (native) and 15 MB (Thrift)
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:29,477 ColumnFamilyStore.java:427 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:29,931 ColumnFamilyStore.java:427 - Initializing system.batches
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:29,935 ColumnFamilyStore.java:427 - Initializing system.paxos
INFO  [main] 2020-12-29 22:29:29,947 ColumnFamilyStore.java:427 - Initializing system.local
INFO  [SSTableBatchOpen:6] 2020-12-29 22:29:29,978 BufferPool.java:234 - Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exhausted (max is 512.000MiB) it will allocate on heap
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000107d65ab8, pid=53674, tid=0x0000000000008203
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_275) (build 1.8.0_275-bre_2020_11_16_16_29-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.275-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x565ab8]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.53674
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/my_laptop/hs_err_pid53674.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I honestly have very little knowledge of Java, or Cassandra, so I'm not sure where the issue might be. I find it weird that the error has `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ...` at the beginning even after I uninstalled the openjdk via homebrew, and removed it with `rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk`.

Any idea what I might try to get it working?

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually got it to work:

Uninstalled Cassandra

```
$ brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V                             
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    15.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 15.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_275, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_275`
$ brew install cassandra
$ vim /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.9_1/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh
```

Change JAVA_HOME to:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_275`
```

Then finally, cross your fingers and run:

```
brew services start cassandra
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think java 15 is supported.

Cassandra 4 adds support for Java 11:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/java11.html

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work, had to really dig around with a bunch of config/java version stuff that's unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue.

1. make sure you have the right java version, not only installed, but as your environmental variables.
2. make sure your cassandra version fits your java version
   https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/new/java11.html
3. when I try to run cassandra with cassandra -f command I have this error messages

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000109d8bb3c, pid=98066, tid=0x0000000000001b03
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_312) (build 1.8.0_312-bre_2022_01_01_23_04-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.312-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x545b3c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/dvegamar/hs_err_pid98066.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
```

And of course, it wont connect

```
(base) MACPRO:~ dvegamar$ cqlsh
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/4.0.3/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py:460: DeprecationWarning: Legacy execution parameters will be removed in 4.0. Consider using execution profiles.
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

but in this same situation if I run with brew services start cassandra it works

```
(base) MACPRO:~ dvegamar$ brew services start cassandra
==> Successfully started `cassandra` (label: homebrew.mxcl.cassandra)
(base) MACPRO:~ dvegamar$ cqlsh
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/4.0.3/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py:460: DeprecationWarning: Legacy execution parameters will be removed in 4.0. Consider using execution profiles.
/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/4.0.3/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py:490: DeprecationWarning: Setting the consistency level at the session level will be removed in 4.0. Consider using execution profiles and setting the desired consitency level to the EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT profile.
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> 
cqlsh>
Connection closed by foreign host...
```